# I want to show Bar Chart but can't work well

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a DataFrame(name: df_buy_sum) like this.
This is Pandas DataFrame.

```
                            BUY
exec_date                      
2018-04-06 17:14:00    9.408225
2018-04-06 17:15:00   89.558326
2018-04-06 17:16:00   88.607791
2018-04-06 17:17:00  108.968230
2018-04-06 17:18:00   80.283624
2018-04-06 17:19:00   50.469037
2018-04-06 17:20:00   74.773105
2018-04-06 17:21:00  115.339747
2018-04-06 17:22:00   84.019508
2018-04-06 17:23:00   44.809346
2018-04-06 17:24:00   31.855530
```

I tried to show BarChart but I can't do it. I can only show Line Chart.

I've written,

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
.
.
ax.bar(df_buy_sum.index,df_buy_sum['BUY'])
```

but output is like this.

[image]

What is a points that have failed ,and How to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
df_buy_sum.plot(kind='bar')
```

Complete example

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot

d = pd.date_range('2007-04-25', periods=50)
s = pd.Series(range(50), index=d)
s.plot(kind='bar')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: but When I use Real Time data, it does't work well.
I think a code 

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, plot, interval=120)
    plt.show()

It made something and can't show BarChar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving figsize to increase the size of your bargraph.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6)) #here you can increase window size of chart
ax = fig.gca() # define axis                   
ax.bar(df_buy_sum.index,df_buy_sum['BUY'])
```